# How to scan IBeacon constantly on Android (Xamarin.Android)?

Tags: android, xamarin, bluetooth, ibeacon, beacon

I'm working on a cross-platform (iOS/Android) Xamarin app, in which I need to scan IBeacon devices to assert the distance between them and the phone device.

On iOS, I use the native iOS iBeacon API, which works flawlessly and as expected.
On Android, since Android does not natively support iBeacon, I use a mix of my own code and a library "[UniversalBeacon](https://github.com/andijakl/universal-beacon)". This approach *works*, but when it comes to scanning (or "ranging") for Beacons over a period of time, in order to constantly assess the distance of the phone device, the experince proves very unreliable.

I am experiencing that incoming BLE packets come in as expected, but only in intervals.
Roughly summarized: Packets will come in, in a steady stream, for a seemingly random amount of time, before the packets eventually stop coming in entirely. Then, after another seemingly random amount time, packets will start coming in again. This process repeats indefinitely.

So my question is: What is causing this issue? Is it an Android quirk that I somehow have to work around?

Initiating the scan:

```
_ScanCallback.OnAdvertisementPacketReceived += ScanCallback_OnAdvertisementPacketReceived;

var settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
    .SetScanMode(ScanMode.LowLatency)
    .Build();

_Adapter.BluetoothLeScanner.StartScan(null, settings, _ScanCallback);
```

Callback implementation:

```
internal class BLEScanCallback : ScanCallback
{
    public event EventHandler<BLEAdvertisementPacketArgs> OnAdvertisementPacketReceived;

    public override void OnScanFailed([GeneratedEnum] ScanFailure errorCode)
    {
        base.OnScanFailed(errorCode);
    }

    public override void OnScanResult([GeneratedEnum] ScanCallbackType callbackType, ScanResult result)
    {
        base.OnScanResult(callbackType, result);

        switch (result.Device.Type)
        {
            case BluetoothDeviceType.Le:
            case BluetoothDeviceType.Unknown:
                try
                {
                    var p = new BLEAdvertisementPacket
                    {
                        BluetoothAddress = result.Device.Address.ToNumericAddress(),
                        RawSignalStrengthInDBm = (short)result.Rssi,

                        Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(result.TimestampNanos / 1000000),

                        AdvertisementType = (BLEAdvertisementType)result.ScanRecord.AdvertiseFlags,
                        Advertisement = new BLEAdvertisement
                        {
                            LocalName = result.ScanRecord.DeviceName
                        }
                    };

                    if (result.ScanRecord.ServiceUuids != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var svc in result.ScanRecord.ServiceUuids)
                        {
                            var guid = new Guid(svc.Uuid.ToString());
                            var data = result.ScanRecord.GetServiceData(svc);

                            p.Advertisement.ServiceUuids.Add(guid);
                        }
                    }

                    var recordData = result.ScanRecord.GetBytes();
                    var rec = RecordParser.Parse(recordData);

                    foreach (var curRec in rec)
                    {
                        if (curRec is BLEManufacturerData md)
                        {
                            p.Advertisement.ManufacturerData.Add(md);
                        }
                        if (curRec is BLEAdvertisementDataSection sd)
                        {
                            p.Advertisement.DataSections.Add(sd);
                        }
                    }
                    OnAdvertisementPacketReceived?.Invoke(this, new BLEAdvertisementPacketArgs(p));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debugger.Break();
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I've read in various articles that this could be caused by Android automatically suspending the scan in order to save power. Whether this is the case is not obvious to me, as there does not seem to be much support on the subject.

I've already tried the following:

- Changing `ScanMode` to `LowPower`/`Balanced` - no change
- Scanning with a filter set to the specific Beacon I was testing with - filter worked, but no change in regards to the issue
- Implementing logic that restarts the scan in set intervals to work around potentional limits for scan duration imposed by Android - did not affect the issue
- Using other, more broadly used libraries, such as [Shiny.Beacons](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Shiny.Beacons/) - same experience

The issue is not caused by the Beacon device itself not advertising correctly - I've made sure of this by scanning it on another device, at the same time as my app. It is the app itself that stops scanning and/or receiving its advertisement packets.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Is this problem in the foreground or background?  Issues may be specific to OEM customizations -- what is you device model and Android version for testing?  (Testing with a Pixel device with stock Android is helpful if possible.)   It is also possible that something in the Xamarin bindings is blocking delivery of beacon detections.  You may be able to check this by looking at native Android logs in LogCat.  What you want is certainly possible with Xamarin on Android -- but I have always done it in a hybrid app where the beacon detection code is all native using my Android Beacon Library.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reaching out.

I'm somewhat a novice in terms of app development, so forgive me if I'm not 100% familiar with the relevant terms. As I understand, "running in the backround" means the scanner is scanning while the app is closed/minimized, while "running in the foreground" means the app is open and interactable by the user. Given that this distinction is correct, my app is scanning for bluetooth/Beacons in the foreground.  

How do I get logs through LogCat in a Xamarin application?  

I'm debugging on a OnePlus Nord CE (EB2103) running Android 11 (Oxygen OS 11).

Comment: Yes, foreground just means the app is visible on the screen.  Use a console on a laptop connected by USB with `adb logcat` to get a native log — you may get useful info at the time the scan stops.  Look for lines that say Bluetooth or Scan.  OnePlus is notorious for proprietary changes to Android (esp. background changes), but I would expect it to work fine in the foreground.  You might also try my BeaconScope app in the play store — it is all native, but if you see that  it scans continually on the OnePlus then that eliminates a OnePlus problem.

Comment: I'll be sure to try out `logcat` to get the native log. I tried your neat app on my phone (OnePlus), however it seems to also suffer from the issues. The scan stability seems more or less on par with what I experience on my end. For clarity, i recorded 2 minutes of scanning using your app: https://streamable.com/yotyo2. So everything more or less points to OnePlus' proprietary OS messing with the scan, yes? This was also my initial hunch, however tests on other phones (Samsung, Huawei) had the same issue.

Comment: I am very surprised to hear you get dropouts on Samsung phones after a couple of minutes in the foreground.  That really isn't normal.  I have a Samsung A10 with Android 11, and I can use the BeaconScope app to detect beacons for much longer than two minutes.  Are you certain about seeing this with BeaconScope on the your Samsung?  If so, something else must explain the difference in your results and mine.

Comment: Sorry, I worded that poorly - I've only tested BeaconScope on the OnePlus. What I meant to convey was that I know from testing that _my_ app has trouble scanning on the different phones mentioned, as to rule out that it was simply a OnePlus problem, at least in context of the app I'm working on

Comment: @davidgyoung I obtained some logs of the scanning process with `logcat`. The only thing that immediately stands out (at least to me) is this fairly common line:

```BtGatt.GattService: Skipping data matching denylist: ScanRecord [mAdvertiseFlags=6, mServiceUuids=null, mServiceSolicitationUuids=[], mManufacturerSpecificData={76=[2, 21, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -78, 0, -78, -58]}, mServiceData={}, mTxPowerLevel=-2147483648, mDeviceName=FlexyBox Test Beacon, mTDSData=null]```

Comment: Does this have any significance? "FlexyBox Test Beacon" is the name of one of the Beacons I am testing with. I am scanning without any explicitly provided `ScanFilter`, so I am confused as to why the Beacon is even in the "denylist". In contrary to this logged line, I DO get packets for this very Beacon... 

Comment: The manufacturer data shown in the deny filter log line is an iBeacon patter.  Apps targeting Android 12+ must obtain location permission from the user otherwise iBeacon adverts are filtered out.  Have you obtained location permission?

Comment: Yes, included in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />```

I request the permissions through the app (I've confirmed that they are given through the phone's perms manager)

Comment: I highly doubt that this is a permissions issue, seeing as I can read the Beacon, just not in a reliable stream

Comment: Maybe that log line is a red herring.  Can you record a longer logcat excerpt and then look for logs a few seconds before and after your detections drop out?